# nginx and docker services won't connect (111: Connection refused)

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I have a node fastify server running with port 3005.
and a reverse proxy on nginx that should proxy to service the node server.

I tried so many configurations, but none worked. Would be great if someone got a hint.

---

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
upstream client {
  server md_license_server:3005;
}
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://client;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
         }
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  md_license_server:
   image: root/md-license-server
   expose:
    - 3005
   ports:
    - 3005:3005
  nginx:
   image: nginx:latest
   container_name: nginx
   ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
   volumes:
    - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs
    - /etc/ssl/private:/etc/ssl/private
    - /root/docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Testing some endpoints from a browser returns:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.21.4</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are these endpoints that you are testing? how  your testing (command use to test), or postman, or... etc ? did you try to bypass nginx and test directly , then you test thru nginx ? if so: what are the results of all these tests.

Comment: i tried to bypass nginx by using curl internally. the node js app was reachable from there. example: curl 127.0.0.1:3005/ping  returns: true

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue caused by fastify.

Solution:

https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/935